# Can I boil bratwurst in beer to cook them?

Tags: grilling, sausages, beer

I bought Red Hook Bratwurts today, and I'm making them tomorrow. Does anyone know if I could boil them in beer since it already was pre made with beer (Red Hook), or would it not be a good idea?

Also, how long do you cook Brats on the grill or oven?

Comment: You can certainly simmer them in beer, but that's a totally different thing than beer battering. Beer battering would mean that you are coating the bratwurst, kind of like a corn dog.

Comment: Please try to only ask one question in any question.... How long you cook the brats should be printed on the packaging as it depends on the ones you get. If they're precooked, they likely don't **need** to be cooked at all and if they're raw, the type of meat/s and size will determine how long they need to cook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that they are uncooked, you can certainly simmer your brats in beer (don't let them boil, that will burst them). I'd try to get a hold of some Red Hook and use that. Simmer them gently until they are *almost* done, about 15 minutes. Simmering in beer will only intensify the beeriness of the brat. If you like beer, go for it. If you've got time, do one in advance and see how you like it. You can dilute the beer with water or broth if you find the test brat too strong.

Consider adding some whole spices, garlic and onion to the beer and simmering them for 10 minutes before adding the bratwurst. Here's a [recipe](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/food-network-kitchens/beer-bratwursts-recipe.html) for exactly that. (That recipe looks outstanding, BTW)

Cover the pan and let the almost cooked bratwurst cool in the beer (seasoned or not). The recipe I linked to says to cool completely, but just 20 minutes or so is plenty. By then any carry-over cooking is done, but the brats would still be warm.  Then just grill or brown on the stove *just* for browning, they will already be cooked through, so it's just the browning that you're looking for. Just let your eyes be your guide and don't go past medium heat (again, they will burst if your heat is too high).

Comment: This is pretty much exactly how I make beer brats (whether pre-made with beer or not). I don't add the spices (though it's a good idea), and I usually use a brown ale (Old Brown Dog is a great one) as it gives the brats a bit of malty-caramelization. I also add sliced onions to the beer and you get some soft, delicious beer-y sweet onions to put on the brats.

Comment: I like to give them a quick, hard sear before adding the beer (or cider--my preference). The marks make it look more attractive and I like the texture difference.